# Converting binary to decimal in C++ without using conditionals

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on an assignment which requires me to write a program in C++ to convert a binary number inputted by the user into its decimal counterpart. Doesn't sound too complicated, right? Well, we can't use any form of conditional statements, we can't use strings, we can't use the binary-to-decimal function (can't remember which library it's in, but I know it exists). Basically, we can't use anything we haven't learned in class.

I suppose it would be easier to open with what we have learned in class:

- Importing libraries
- Assigning values to variables
- Basic mathematic operators

I believe that a good place to start would be with modular division, I just don't really know how I'd go about obtaining a correct answer without using conditionals. I've been sitting here and raking my brain for the last 48 hours, but I still just haven't had that a-ha moment.

Thanks for help in advance!

EDIT: For what it's worth, we are told to assume that the values are unsigned and have a maximum size of 4 bits.

Comment: Just use a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and you're done.

Comment: Think about a simpler example.  How would you convert a 1-digit binary number into its decimal equivalent?  How about 2 digits?

Comment: What does it mean "you cannot use string"? Do you mean the standard class `std::string` right? However you can use a simple `char*`, can't you?

Comment: Does this mean you aren't allowed to breathe because you didn't learn it in class? Dang, that's rough. Hope you can code fast.

Comment: Specifically, we were told "You are not allowed to use something that will
automatically convert your binary number to a decimal number, and you are not
allowed to use strings, conditional statements, or loops/repetition"

I don't see why we wouldn't be allowed to use chars, seeing as those are one of the data types we have gone over.

Comment: What is the "input"?  Is it a typed string that the user enters into the console such as "101010111" ?  Or something else?

Comment: There's no guidelines as to how it has to be inputted. I was thinking about having the user input each digit from the binary number one at a time.

Comment: I can see a recursive function to get around the no loops, but even recursion needs to test a condition sooner or later to exit, though I suppose you can use an exception as a hack. But seriously, confirm the no conditional rules with the instructor.

Comment: @user4581301 it's already been confirmed, it's written in bold letters on the assignment sheet. No strings/conditionals/loops/repetition.

Comment: Max 4. There we go. Now this is possible.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know how I managed to look over that part when reading the assignment. I feel like a roadblock in my mind was cleared, but I'm still definitely not nearing the end of the road.

Answer (score 2):

If you were allowed to use loops, it would be this simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str("1101");
    int result = 0;

    for(int i=str.size()-1, pos=0; i>=0; --i, ++pos)
        result += str[i] == '0'? 0 : 1 << pos;

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

But do this without loops or recursion? Who said you have to be accurate!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
long long  not_very_accurate(long long input)
{
    long long power = ceil(log10(input+1));
    return std::pow(2, power);
}

int main()
{
    long long input = 1011010110;
    std::cout << not_very_accurate(input) << std::endl; //almost the same :)
}
```

Maximum error is up to 2 times of the real result. More `1`es used, the better result.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, this is how you would do it for two bits:

```
int main()
{
    int binary;
    cin >> binary;
    int decimal = 2*(binary/10) + binary%10;
    cout << decimal << '\n';
}
```

Example:

If binary==11, then

> 2*(11/10) + (11%10) == 3

Answer (score 1):

Since you said in the comments below that the input is limited to 4 bits, it becomes straightforward with only a few expanded expressions to handle the 4 or 5 different input lengths.

The guiding trick here is that boolean expressions such as `str[0] == '1'` will get implicitly cast to a zero or one.  And then "math" can be done on those bits.

Since this is clearly homework, I'm not going to finish it for you.  If you need to remove the `table` array member variable because arrays haven't been introduced in your class yet, that's up to you.  But it can be done if you use the examples already provided.

On a final note, StackOverflow doesn't exist as your personal [Mechanical Turk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk) to do your homework for you.  In the future, you need to demonstrate what you've already tried and articulate what you are stuck on to get assistance.

```
int DecimalFromBinary(char* str)
{
    int result = 0;

    int len = (str[0] != '\0') +
        ((str[0] != '\0') && (str[1] != '\0')) +
        ((str[0] != '\0') && (str[1] != '\0') && (str[2] != '\0')) +
        ((str[0] != '\0') && (str[1] != '\0') && (str[2] != '\0') && (str[3] != '\0'));

    int table[5] = { 1,8,4,2,1 };

    result += (str[0] == '1') * 8;
    result += ((len > 1) && (str[1] == '1')) * 4;
    result += ((len > 2) && (str[2] == '1')) * 2;
    result += ((len > 3) && (str[3] == '1')) * 1;

    result /= table[len];

    // printf("%d\n", result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: We are unable to use loops in this program.

Comment: @Benzel Are integer types types allowed? Who is so evil to disallow loops?

Comment: @BlackMoses integer types are indeed allowed. I'm not really sure why the professor doesn't allow loops, I think it's to throw off the people who come in with coding experience, because she really stresses that she wants newcomers and veterans alike to feel equal. Unfortunately, even the TA's are confused by the assignment and thought that there had to be a typo or something.

Comment: At the end of the day, there has to be a "stopping condition".  Do you think the instructor is trying to teach recursion, dynamic programming, or some other concept?

Comment: @selbie I don't believe so, we're only in the first week of a first year computer science class. For what it's worth, we are told to assume that all numbers are unsigned and that the max binary number is 4 bits.

Comment: Oh, well that changes everything... :)

Comment: @selbie I'm still completely lost :/

Comment: Give me about five minutes. I'm about to blow your mind.

Comment: @selbe unfortunately, I don't believe we are allowed to utilize tables, either, seeing as we haven't gone over them in class. I'll email the professor and see how they feel about it, though. But I do think that you're onto something. Rather than using a table, I believe I could prompt the user for the numbers one at a time and then use modular division to tell if they input a 1 or a 0, then store the correlating value in a variable and add them all up at the end, correct?

Comment: That'll fail the empty string test, but I'm not sure if no bits is considered a valid input. Never mind. Missed the edit.

Comment: @user4581301 - I just fixed that.

Comment: @Benzel - removing the array (table) is an exercise I'll leave up to you.  It can be done if you think in terms of mapping boolean expressions to 1 or 0 as I have already demonstrated.  It's all "maths" from here. :)

Comment: I would be more worried about the instructor's view of `strlen` and `strncpy`, because they are basically function-wrapped loops, than the array.

Comment: @selbie
Yeah, I have confirmed that we are not allowed to use the strlen and strncpy functions

Comment: I updated the solution for the **last** time to remove the strncpy and strlen.  But I'm going to still leave the exercise of removing the table array update up to you.  You need to do your own homework.  I've gotten you 80% of the way there.  Now you need take it home!  Selbie out.  <mic drop>

Comment: Opinion selbie: is this a reasonable question for the first weeks of an intro to programming course?

Comment: It's a very reasonable question for a comp sci program that wants to encourage students to think and apply problem solving skills rather than just teach whatever the hottest programming languages are.  Computer Science is essentially the science of solving problems.  Not sure where you go to school, but I already have respect for it if they are assigning homework like this to freshmen.

Comment: What I like about this question is there are a lot of totally different ways to approach it, including some really deep rabbit holes. It's not immediately obvious whether it should be approached with string manipulation (your answer's great by the way. Didn't think this was do-able with strings), bit flipping, or good old arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Prompts the user for a binary number and then returns the decimal equivalent without making use of conditionals/loops

    int first_bit;
    int second_bit;
    int third_bit;
    int fourth_bit;
    int decimal;

    cout << "What is the first digit in your 4-bit binary number?" << endl;
    cin >> first_bit;
    cout << "What is the second digit in your 4-bit binary number?" << endl;
    cin >> second_bit;
    cout << "What is the third digit in your 4-bit binary number?" << endl;
    cin >> third_bit;
    cout << "What is the fourth digit in your 4-bit binary number?" << endl;
    cin >> fourth_bit;
    cout << "Your 4-bit binary number is " << first_bit << second_bit << third_bit << fourth_bit << endl;

    decimal = ((first_bit) * pow(2, 3)) + ((second_bit) * pow(2, 2)) + ((third_bit) * pow(2, 1)) + ((fourth_bit) * pow(2, 0));

    cout << "The decimal equivalent of " << first_bit << second_bit << third_bit << fourth_bit << " is " << decimal << endl;
```

Hey guys, finally worked out an answer for my question. It may not be an ideal method of receiving user input for the 4-bit binary number, but it was the simplest process I could think of that didn't involve using loops or conditionals, and it churns out the correct answer every time. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Absolutely certain that violates the instructor's intent and will earn you a low mark. Take a look at what @VaughnCato did in their answer, then extend the math to 3 bits and finally 4.

Comment: Note for the future: `pow` is designed for computing nasty stuff like pi to the e. It is is vast and utter overkill for multiplying 2 or 3 integers together. You are generally a lot better off going `2*2*2`. For one thing, the compiler will see `2*2*2` as a constant and multiply it out for you while building the program. There will be no runtime costs and the intent of `2*2*2` should be just as plain as `pow(2,3)` to most readers.

Comment: @user4581301 in the prior CS course I took with the same prof, the code itself didn't really matter as long as it was readable and returned the correct answer, so I'm not too worried about losing points over the method I chose to use. I will make sure to remember those comments about pow in the future, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner, and this is what I figured out...

Please let me know if this code can be improved

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int psuedo, bin,q, rem;
cout<<"Enter a binary number: ";
cin>> bin;

int num=0;
psuedo = bin;            
while(q!=0){
    q=psuedo/10;      // psuedo helps us to count number of digits used in binary
    num++;            // num represents number of digits in binary
    psuedo=q;
}
int dec=0;
for(int i =0; i<num; i++){
    rem = bin%10;
    dec = (rem*pow(2,i))+dec;     // conversion to decimal number from binary
    q = bin/10;
    bin = q;
}

cout<<"The decimal number is: "<<dec<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Example:

input bin = 0101

output dec = 5